# Regex to get a string between 2 strings, ignoring the start and end

Tags: regex, vb.net

using `regex` to get a string between 2 strings and can't figure out how to ignore the start and end strings.

```
"imgurl=(.*?)&amp"
```

this expression working fine except i need to  ignore `imgurl=` and  `&amp`?

by matching the following string:

```
imgurl=mytext&amp
```

the result i got is like

```
imgurl=mytext&amp
```

it has to be

```
mytext
```

Comment: The `mytext` part will be in captured group 1 (indicated by the first set of brackets in the regex). What language/framework are you using for the regex? Often \1 or $1 refer to whatever's matched by the first  set of brackets.

Comment: Telling us what language you're programming in might help in perl you are able to use $1 after matching something like that
in php you have to add another variable at the end of the regexp_match and use the [1] index of that variable to see the correct result

Comment: @mathematical.coffee i am using VB.NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't specified the language, but be sure you are checking the appropriate match group...

```
>>> msg = "imgurl=mytext&amp"
>>> import re
>>> foo = re.search("imgurl=(.*?)&amp", msg)
>>> foo.group(1)
'mytext'
>>> foo.group(0)
'imgurl=mytext&amp'
```

Obviously, group 1 is what you're looking for...

EDIT

For vb.net code..

```
Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("imgurl=(.*?)&amp")
Dim match As Match = regex.Match("imgurl=mytext&amp")
```

Assuming you get the match, you need the value from `match.Groups(1).Value`

Comment: For future readers: if your text spans across mutliple lines (contains newline symbols), you need to use `RegexOptions.Singleline` flag when compiling the Regex object.